# Python division by 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, division

I want to count the trailing zeroes of the factorial of a number. When I divide the number by 10 I expect the last zero to be removed but it doesn't.

```
def fact(num):
    if (num==0 or num==1):
        return 1
    else:
        return num*fact(num-1)

def num(a):
    f = fact(a)
    count = 0
    while(f%10==0):
        count=count+1
        print(f)
        f=int(f/10)
        print(f)
    return count

n=int(input())
while(n!=0):
    a=int(input())
    print(num(a))
    n=n-1
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Can't reproduce. How do you call `fact`? Are you sure there aren't prints anywhere else?

Comment: What input are you providing? Be aware that factorial calculations can quickly run into overflows.

Comment: added the complete program

Comment: You can use `//` for int division. `/` is float division, which loses precision.

Comment: For an input of 60, the factorial runs into ```long```. And, in your function ```num``` you're trying to cast it into ```int``` thereby losing precision. You may need```f = long(f/10)```.

Comment: Fun fact: `math.factorial` is a standard library function.

Comment: another fun fact: `num(fact(n))` is simply `n//5`

Comment: @SanilSinaiBorkar In Python there is no distinction between `int`  and `long` (`long` doesn't exist).

Comment: @Demi-Lune, I haven't checked/verified, but is this because there's always some multiplication of 2 and 5 (mod 10) involved (resulting in an additional trailing 0)?

Comment: @00, yes to be divisible by 10, you need a 5 and a 2. Fives are the less frequent ones, every second 5 that appears is already a 10, every odd multiple of 5 is preceded in fact(n) by an even number, etc. This is not a proper proof, but I hope it is enough clues to see the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace:

```
f=int(f/10)
```

with

```
f = f // 10
```

inside `num()` function. It will fix your problem.

---

**Explanation:**

`f/10` converts the number to a `float`. And when you convert that `float` to `int` it loses the precision in case of a big number.

You can confirm it by doing this:

```
a = 8320987112741390144276341183223364380754172606361245952449277696409600000000000000

print(int(a/10)) # prints: 832098711274139031630889608027340070244161333703152098685794054394185233318543360

print(a//10) # prints: 832098711274139014427634118322336438075417260636124595244927769640960000000000000
```