# Function that receives an integer n>0 and tells whether its digits (in base 10) form a nondecreasing sequence (each digit is >= to the previous one)

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Write a function nondec(n) that receives an integer n>0 and reports whether its digits (in base 10) form a nondecreasing sequence (that is, each digit is greater or equal to the previous one).

I am having trouble with this exercise. My code so far is:

```
def nondec(n):
    '''
    >>> nondec(113355779)
    True
    >>> nondec(44569)
    True
    >>> nondec(346234)
    False
    >>> nondec(222)
    True
    >>> nondec(789)
    True
    >>> nondec(55555)
    True
    >>> nondec(1234123)
    False
    >>> nondec(98765)
    False
    '''
    prev = 9
    while n>0 :
        lastdigit = n%10
        if lastdigit > prev:
            return False
        prev = lastdigit
        n = n/10
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

It works for all cases but for those with repeated digits: 222, 55555. I tried many things but it makes my code worse. Thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to use modules from the standard library? E.g., this is a one-liner using the `re` module: `nondec = lambda n: bool(re.fullmatch("1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*", str(n)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is the code you are looking for:

```
def nondec(n):
    '''
    >>> nondec(113355779)
    True
    >>> nondec(44569)
    True
    >>> nondec(346234)
    False
    >>> nondec(222)
    True
    >>> nondec(789)
    True
    >>> nondec(55555)
    True
    >>> nondec(1234123)
    False
    >>> nondec(98765)
    False
    '''
    prev = 9
    while n>0 :
        lastdigit = n % 10
        if lastdigit > prev:
            return False
        prev = lastdigit
        n = n // 10
    return True
```

The only change I did to your code is to the part that you do the division with 10: `n = n / 10`.

The problem was that this division returned a `float` but you wanted an `int`

For example if you take `222` when it divides by `10` then the new value of `n` was `22.2` when you wanted it to be `22`. (You can check for such problems by printing the results of every line of code you write!)

You can accomplish this by using the `//` instead of `/`.

You can check this answer [Python division by 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61075108/18164421) to see what I am talking about

Comment: @Alba Generally it is a good tactic to print the results of your code for debugging and to have a better overview of the program you make. For example here if you had printed `n` after each iteration you would have easily spotted that `n` was being a `float` after each division by `10`.

Comment: Thanks I'm trying that and it's really useful. I will do it often then :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
def nondec(n):
    return all(int(x)<=int(y) for x,y in zip(str(n), str(n)[1:]))
```

Test it:

```
for n in (113355779,44569,346234,222,789,55555,1234123,98765):
    print(n, nondec(n))
```

Prints:

```
113355779 True
44569 True
346234 False
222 True
789 True
55555 True
1234123 False
98765 False
```

Since `'0'<'1' ... '8'<'9'` you actually can work with strings all the way through:

```
def nondec(n):
    s=str(n)
    return all(x<=y for x,y in zip(s, s[1:]))

    # same result...
```

Answer (score 0):

another more linguistic way to do it:

```
def nondec(n):
    '''
    >>> nondec(113355779)
    True
    >>> nondec(44569)
    True
    >>> nondec(346234)
    False
    >>> nondec(222)
    True
    >>> nondec(789)
    True
    >>> nondec(55555)
    True
    >>> nondec(1234123)
    False
    >>> nondec(98765)
    False
    '''
    n = str(n)
    for e,_ in enumerate(n):
        if e:
            if int(n[e]) < int(n[e-1]):
                return False 
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

The variable `n` should be an integer. You should cast `n` to `int` inside your loop.

```
def nondec(n):
    '''
    >>> nondec(113355779)
    True
    >>> nondec(44569)
    True
    >>> nondec(346234)
    False
    >>> nondec(222)
    True
    >>> nondec(789)
    True
    >>> nondec(55555)
    True
    >>> nondec(1234123)
    False
    >>> nondec(98765)
    False
    '''
    prev = 9
    while n > 0:
        lastdigit = n % 10
        if lastdigit > prev:
            return False
        prev = lastdigit
        n = int(n / 10)
    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest

    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```